# How to find inverse of elements in a very large $\mathbb{Z}_n$ group?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, computational-mathematics, computational-number-theory

Suppose I have an element $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n$ is thousands of digits(base 10) and $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Is there a computationally efficient way of finding the inverse of $a$? or just any way to find the inverse of $a$ some time in this decade?

**Edit 1:** I am a fan of python if you would like to answer with an actual algorithm.

**Update:** The extended Euclidean Algorithm will do it (Python below):

```
def inverse(a, n):
    t    = 0
    newt = 1
    r    = n
    newr = a

    while newr != 0:
        quotient  = r//newr
        (t, newt) = (newt, t - quotient*newt) 
        (r, newr) = (newr, r - quotient*newr)

    if r > 1:
        return "a is not invertible"
    if t < 0:
        t = t + n

    return t
```

Comment: cf. [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euclidean algorithm is very fast. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: Care to elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: I added a link to Wikipedia. The algorithm gives, in particular, $u,v$ such that $ua+vn=1$. This $u$ is the inverse of $a$.

Comment: I am sure this has been implemented in Python already.

Comment: It works in $\approx \log n$ time.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I just tested it.